# Can Montgomery ladder multiplication be used with secp256k1?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, montgomery-ladder

While reading about Elliptical Curves and ECDSA, I found a paper [*ECDSA Security in Bitcoin and Ethereum: a Research Survey*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1785/6bad4335c8ca7419aab2c715ea25ce5e0621.pdf) by Hartwig Mayer. On page 6, the authors say:

> The curve secp256k1 does not allow the Montgomery ladder
>   implementation.

Is this true? And if so, why? I don't see why [Montgomery methods](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/293.pdf) wouldn't be usable with secp256k1.

Answer (score 7):

The [Montgomery ladder](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7.pdf), in particular Montgomery's fast doubling and differential addition formula in $(X : Z)$ coordinates on p. 261, works only for curves which admit a Montgomery form $B y^2 = x^3 + A x^2 + x$.  Any curve over a field $k$ with a Montgomery form necessarily has a point of order 2 among the $k$-rational points, namely $P = (0, 0)$: the [negation map](http://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom.html) sends $(x, y)$ to $(x, -y)$, so since $-P = (0, -0) = (0, 0) = P$, we must have $[2]P = P + P = P - P = \mathcal O$.

secp256k1 is the curve $y^2 = x^3 + 7$ over the field $\mathbb F_p$ where $p = 2^{256} - 2^{32} - 977$.  Its group of $\mathbb F_p$-rational points has large prime order, so by Lagrange's theorem it has no points of order 2, and hence it does not have a Montgomery form.

That said, there is a *much slower* single-coordinate ladder that encourages constant-time arithmetic, namely the [Brier–Joye ladder](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-45664-3_24.pdf), which works for any short Weierstrass curve $y^2 = x^3 - a x + b$ including secp256k1.  It is so much slower that the standard variable-time addition chains for short Weierstrass curves are tempting, which is why [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/ladder.html) recommends, for Diffie–Hellman protocols, the use of $x$-restricted DH functions in Montgomery curves instead to avoid a conflict between efficiency and security in implementation.

This doesn't matter as much for signature, which is what Bitcoin *etc.* use secp256k1 for, because most signature schemes—ECDSA as used by Bitcoin and Ethereum, and by those who are forced to comply with bureaucratic standards; EdDSA as used by everyone else—involve the $y$ coordinate, which neither ladder computes; fixed-base-point scalar multiplication, which can be done faster than variable-base-point scalar multiplication; and multiple-point scalar multiplications, which can be done faster than multiple single-point scalar multiplications.  There are signature schemes computed with single-coordinate ladders, such as [qDSA](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/518), but these are a little exotic and not much used—certainly not in Bitcoin or Ethereum!

Comment: I would argue that the Montgomery ladder is an *exponentiation* algorithm, which works for any structure that has a doubling and differential addition operation. In particular it can be used in any group, so I think your first sentence is a little misleading. Of course the question whether it is efficient is another matter!

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast I guess you could say the Montgomery ladder is the general exponentiation algorithm with doubling and differential addition which can be instantiated with Montgomery's double and differential-add formulae on Montgomery curves, or with Brier and Joye's double and differential-add formulae on any short Weierstrass curves, but usually I've just seen the instantiations named ‘the Montgomery ladder’ _vs._ ‘the Brier–Joye ladder’. The algorithm is apparently so obvious that Montgomery didn't bother to spell it out and just called it ‘the binary method’ with a one-line summary.

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast I emphasized that what makes the Montgomery ladder peculiar to Montgomery curves is Montgomery's fast doubling and addition in XZ coordinates in curves of that form.  Better?

Comment: Very minor note: Brier-Joye ladder doesn't work when input point has x=0